# Running for loop depending on size of string vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have made a string vector

```
vector<string> actor_;
```

and then added elements in it using push_back.

I now want to display all of them, for which I need to run a loop according to the number of elements in the vector. For that, I need to run the following loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)actor_.size; i++)
{
}
```

but this returns the following error:

---

```
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'unsigned int (__thiscall std::vector<_Ty>::* )(void) const' to 'int'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=std::string
1>        ]
1>        There is no context in which this conversion is possible
```

---

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`size` is a member function; you mean:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < actor_.size(); i++) { }
```

(it's a good idea to use `std::size_t` instead of `unsigned int` as well)

Comment: oh, silly me...its now working.

Question: why is std::size_t a better idea than unsigned int?

Comment: @James: Just to clarify, he never had `unsigned int` to begin with. (Maybe I'm reading to much into it.) @xbonez: `size_t` is the standard integral type for measuring the size of something, and could very well be bigger than an `unsigned`. `size()` returns a `size_t`, and so you should use a `size_t` to match.

Comment: because size_t will always have the same type as the return type of the size() function, whatever the arch/platform you are compiling to (x86, x86_64, etc..)

Comment: @GMan:  I changed it from `int` to `unsigned` because `int` would likely give a signed/unsigned comparison warning.  I guess I could have just changed it to `size_t`, but I didn't think of that at first...

Comment: Technically, `std::vector<>::size()` returns `std::vector<>::size_type` , which in theory _could_ be something other than `size_t`.  In practice, I don't know of any implementation where it's not `size_t`.

Comment: @Gabriel:  I changed a lot of `unsigned int`s to `size_t`s when modifying our software to 64 bits.  We have some large data structures, which is why the changeover was necessary.

Comment: @GMan:  I've read several sources that claim `std::vector<>::size_type` is "implementation defined".

Comment: The error casting from unsigned int would appear to be a result of the attempt to cast the function pointer to an int - as in "(int)actor_.size". Presumably this is compiled for a 32-bit architecture.

Comment: @Adrian: You are right, it only says it has to be an unsigned integral type.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using an iterator rather than relying on operator[] to access the elements (as implied by you using an integral loop counter and size()).  This would allow you to change the container type in the future should you so wish without having to modify your access code.

Answer (score 1):

The *most* correct would be:

```
for (std::vector<std::string>::size_type i = 0; i < actor_.size(); ++i) {}
```

That's ugly.  You can simplify it with a `typedef`.

C++0x gives us `auto`, but that's easy to misuse:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < actor_.size() ++i) {}  // WRONG
```

Here again, `i` is an `int` (because `0` is an `int`), which means we haven't solved the problem.  Iterators plus `auto` yield something reasonable:

```
for (auto it = actor_.begin(); it != actor_.end(); ++it) {}
```

Another option would be to use `std::for_each` and a lambda.  STL syntax almost always favors iterators over indexes.

Oh, and GMan pointed out that C++0x makes this even easier with range-based `for` loops:

```
for (auto& a : actor_) {}
```

Comment: If we're talking C++0x, I'd prefer: `for ( auto& s : actor_) std::cout << s << std::endl;` Ah, so simple.